# How to fix Navbar UIImagePickerController in iOS 15+ be transparent

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar, ios15, imagepicker

I have a problem with UIImagePickerController when used by iOS 15 device because the navigation bar has a transparent background,

[image]
my expectation is the navbar to stay white like on ios devices below 15
I've used this method but it doesn't work, is there a way to fix this issue?

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
picker.delegate = self
picker.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = .white
    appearance.shadowColor = .white
    appearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
            
    picker.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    picker.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}

viewController.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to  [some old question on Apple forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/133680) regarding `UIImagePickerController` and its navigationBar  it seems that referencing `picker.navigationBar.standardAppearance` cannot really change picker appearence and the only unfortunate solution is to globally change appearence for all `UINavigationBars` by setting its appearence likewise:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
```

Also check if you are not modifying the global appearence somewhere in your code by accident.
Hopefully it helps you, even though it is propably not optimal solution.